# Compare two dictionaries and add missing keys.Values not important at this time

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, compare

`dictionary1` looks like this

```
[DATA_WZD],[WERKZEUG],NUMM=1,GRUP=1,AKR=0,MODE=1,MAGA=1,LAGE=0,DURC=348.2,........NOTCH=130,MANCH=0,RED3=0,NAME="Querschnittblatt 350-3,5mm ",BEME="Bemerkung "
[WERKZEUG],NUMM=2,GRUP=1,MAKR=0,MODE=0,MAGA=0,LAGE=0,DURC=449.6........NOTCH=150,MANCH=0,RED3=0,NAME="Querschnittblatt 450/4,0mm ",BEME="Bemerkung "
[WERKZEUG] and so on.
```

`dictionary2` looks similar, but has extra keys and values

```
[DATA_WZD]
[WERKZEUG],NUMM=1,GRUP=1,MAKR=0,MODE=0,MAGA=0,LAGE=0,DURC=385.8,.......NOTCH=130,MANCH=0,RED3=0,CYCLE=0,CMIN=0,CMAX=0,ACTIVE=1,NAME="Querschnittblatt 35",BEME="Bemerkung"
[WERKZEUG],NUMM=2,GRUP=1,MAKR=0,MODE=0,MAGA=0,LAGE=0,DURC=429.6........NOTCH=150,MANCH=0,RED3=0,CYCLE=0,CMIN=0,CMAX=0,ACTIVE=1,NAME="Querschnittblatt 45",BEME="Bemerkung"
[WERKZEUG].....
```

I want the keys and the values from `dictionary2` which are missing in `dictionary1` to be inserted at the same position in `dictionary2`. should than look like this

```
[DATA_WZD]
[WERKZEUG],NUMM=1,GRUP=1,AKR=0,MODE=1,MAGA=1,LAGE=0,DURC=348.2,........NOTCH=130,MANCH=0,RED3=0,CYCLE=0,CMIN=0,CMAX=0,ACTIVE=1,NAME="Querschnittblatt 350-3,5mm ",BEME="Bemerkung "
[WERKZEUG],NUMM=2,GRUP=1,MAKR=0,MODE=0,MAGA=0,LAGE=0,DURC=449.6........NOTCH=150,MANCH=0,RED3=0,CYCLE=0,CMIN=0,CMAX=0,ACTIVE=1,NAME="Querschnittblatt 450/4,0mm ",BEME="Bemerkung "
[WERKZEUG]......
```

What's a good way of doing this?

Comment: bit of a wall of text there, but anyway: what have you tried so far?

Comment: AFAIK, Position is not a controllable property of a dictionary item.

Comment: Why not cloning dictionary2?

Comment: Use a `SortedDictionary`?

Comment: There is no way to know what you are asking -- 1) It is not clear what is in your dictonary -- you use some text formatting that only means something to you, what are the keys, what are the values?  2) There is an expectation on SO that you have tried to solve the problem. What have you tired, why is it not working?  Please post the **code** that you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Linq:

```
dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(k => dict2.Add(k, dict1[k]));
```

or if you want empty strings instead of dict1 values:

```
dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(k => dict2.Add(k, string.Empty));
```

Comment: The first solution is nealy perfect for what I need exept I only want to add the new keys and values and leave the others as they are. Because this compares the whole lines it will also replace the existing keys and value. Maybe their is a way of just comparing keys

Comment: This does what you ask I think. It just compares Keys and not values. dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys) will give all the keys that exist in dict1 but aren't in dict2. As already mentioned, you can't do anything about position of the keys, as that isn't possible using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to merge two dictionaries in pseudo-code:

Given

```
Dictionary dict1,dict2
```

Do this:

```
Dictionary dictRes = new Dictionary;


for each(key in dict1)
  dictRes.Add(dict1(key));

for each(key in dict2)
  if (not dictRes contains element)
    dictRes.Add(dict2(key));
```